# ImageMagick incorrect filename

Tags: imagemagick

I use command `convert` to resize images. E.g.:

```
convert path/to/src.jpg -resize 100x100^ -gravity Center -crop 100x100^ path/to/src_100.jpg
```

In some cases, the output file is not `src_100.jpg`. but `src_100-0.jpg`. It seems, that imagick adds ["filename reference"](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#output). But the source is just image, not PDF file.

I noticed, this happens when I upload an example of malicious image from scenario #2 from https://dzone.com/articles/some-image-based-exploits-with-their-prevention

But after I upload that image, it happens also with other non-malicious images uploaded.

Is it some sort of bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm testing in on Windows 10.

Comment: Three things to try. Maybe use "-extent" instead of "-crop". Or remove the caret "^" and add "+0+0" to the "-crop" geometry. Or just before the output add "delete 1--1".

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6269#issuecomment-1517964420
The solution is to use `-crop 100x100^+0+0` instead of `-crop 100x100^`